Countable spread implies countable chain condition
Let $X$ be a topological space.
$X$ has countable spread if every discrete subspace of $X$ has countable cardinality.
$X$ verifies the countable chain condition if every collection of pairwise-disjoint non-empty open sets is countable.
I was wondering about how to prove that if a space has countable spread, then it verifies the countable chain condition.

Let $X$ be a space that has countable spread, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of pairwise-disjoint non-empty open sets of $X$.
For each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, select an element $x_A \in A$.
$D = \{x_A : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a discrete subspace of $X$ ($A \cap D = \{x_A\}$, for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$).
The map $f : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow D; A \mapsto x_A$ is bijective (distinct elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are pairwise-disjoint and by the definition of $D$), so $|\mathcal{A}| = |D|$.
As $X$ has countable spread, then $D$ is countable, hence $\mathcal{A}$ is countable too.
